# Regex: First occurrence between two character if there are two characters

Tags: regex

I want to get the first occurrence between two character if both exist, otherwise get what is before the first character found.

For example, on the strings below:

```
25 de Março - Centro Histórico de São Paulo, São Paulo - SP, Brasil
Centro Histórico de São Paulo, São Paulo - SP, Brasil
Rua Hamilton Prado, 398 - Chácara Belenzinho, São Paulo - SP, 03376-000, Brasil
```

I want to get what is behind the '-' character. However, the second string only has one '-', so I want to get everything that is behind it.

The results I am looking for are:

```
Centro Histórico de São Paulo, São Paulo
Centro Histórico de São Paulo, São Paulo
Chácara Belenzinho, São Paulo
```

I tried the following regex `[^-\n]+(?=-[^\n-]*$)` but it does not return what I want on the last string.

Is it possible to solve with regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could optionally match the first part, and capture the second part in a group

```
^(?:.+?- )?(.+?) -
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:.+?- )?` Optionally match as least as possible chars until  `-`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `.+?` Match as least as possible chars
- `) -` Close group and match  `-`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6GLvVD/1)

Or for example with the surrounding spaces and a negated character class matching any char except a newline or `-`

```
^(?:[^\n-]+-)?([^\n-]+)-
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y9ZSQn/1)

Answer (score 1):

IMHO it would be better to loop through the string by yourself.

```js
const str = `25 de Março - Centro Histórico de São Paulo, São Paulo - SP, Brasil
Centro Histórico de São Paulo, São Paulo - SP, Brasil
Rua Hamilton Prado, 398 - Chácara Belenzinho, São Paulo - SP, 03376-000, Brasil`;

const addresses = str
.split('\n')
.map(address => address
    .split(' - ')
    .slice(-2, -1)
).join('\n');

console.log(addresses);
```

The logic is to take the second last part of each address.